DocuSign embedded signing, sudden formatting issue
We have a couple of instances of DocuSign embedded forms in our app. In both cases, the user signs the form using an embedded iframe (using the DS SDK), and both worked fine up until October '24.
One of them is a DS template, that one worked and continues to work.
The other is a PDF that we generate, indicate where the signature goes, and send it to DS on the backend. This one stopped working in our dev environments sometime in the middle of October; every step of the process works as expected, including the formatting, except for the view where the user signs. At that point, the document that they were shown became a relatively unformatted view (like a basic word doc instead of the styling the PDF had).
We asked our rep about it and they told us nothing had changed on their end that should affect the formatting, but nothing changed on our end either, so I doubt that.
We noticed that there is a console error now (that we don't think we saw before):
Error importing mockServiceWorker.js
NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Failed to import 'https://docutest-a.akamaihd.net/integrations/1ds/libs/msw/2.2.11/lib/mockSeviceWorker.js'. importScripts() of new scripts after service worker installation is not allowed.`

along with
Permissions policy violation: Geolocation access has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document.

Our app is React (vite) + Node/Express and we're pulling DocuSign in using their recommended CDK url as an index.html script include.
Any leads? DocuSign blew us off, but we haven't changed anything in code (DocuSign is administered by a different team, but we don't believe any changes have been made) and this error just popped up.
And again, the error first appeared in dev in October, and at that point we tested prod and the error was not occurring. When we checked yesterday we noticed it in prod, also.
We're banging our heads against the wall and I'd love any insight!

Have you opened a support case with Docusign Developer Support? They will be able to investigate, gather detailed information from you that is not possible over stackoverflow, and hopefully lead you to a resolution.

We did. As I mentioned in the post, they basically said "we didn't change anything." We're going to open another one and prod them a bit.

So in our case, the browser error ended up being a red herring.
htmlDefinition: {
  source: 'document',
},

We believe the default behavior changed for this flag we were passing in when creating the Envelope.
Prior to the Oct date, this generated the PDF in PDF format. Now, it causes DS to always create the document in "responsive" HTML format.
We removed this flag completely and it seems to have resolved the problem.
